# Column-wise value replacement based on a condition on each column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace all values in all columns that are below that column's mean value. Right now, I'm doing it in the following way:

```
  mean = data2.mean()

  for i, column in enumerate(data2.columns):
    mask = data2.iloc[:,i] < mean[i]
    data2.loc[mask, column] = mean[i]
```

Is there a better way to do it without using a `for` loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [clip](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html) the values, specifying the lower value as the mean of the columns.

```
#Sample data.
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (5, 3)), columns=list('abc'))
>>> df
   a  b  c
0  6  1  4
1  4  8  4
2  6  3  5
3  8  7  9
4  9  2  7

>>> df.mean()
a    6.6
b    4.2
c    5.8
dtype: float64

>>> df.clip(lower=df.mean(), axis=1)
     a    b    c
0  6.6  4.2  5.8
1  6.6  8.0  5.8
2  6.6  4.2  5.8
3  8.0  7.0  9.0
4  9.0  4.2  7.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,(5,8)))
print(df)

new_df = df[df > df.mean()].fillna(df.mean())
print(new_df)
```